# Mongo db delete key from nested data

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

Mongo database data  here i wants to delete key of report_data
So i i will send key= ber2, report_name=Delete test, name=New folder it will delete only key ber2 from report_data of that report and folder

```
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("6267b4554cbd527bee4c6b3a"),
        "structure" : [
            {
                "name" : "New folder",
                "values" : [
                    {
                        "report_name" : "mixll",
                        "report_heading" : "mixll",
                        "background" : "#f0f2f5",
                        "grid" : false,
                        "report_data" : {
                            "mixchch" : {
                                "datasource" : "New_DGR",
                                "source" : "10",
                                "title" : "mix chch"
                            }
                        },
                        "unique_report_name" : "mixll"
                    },
                    {
                        "report_name" : "Delete test",
                        "report_heading" : "Delete test",
                        "background" : "#f0f2f5",
                        "grid" : false,
                        "report_data" : {
                            "ber2" : {
                                "data" : null,
                                "datasource" : "Restest_0423",
                                "source" : "10",
                                "title" : "ber 2"
                            },
                            "piechart" : {
                                "data" : null,
                                "datasource" : "Restest_0423",
                                "source" : "10",
                                "title" : "pie chart"
                            },
                            "lnechart" : {
                                "data" : null,
                                "datasource" : "Restest_0423",
                                "source" : "10",
                                "title" : "lne chart"
                            }
                        },
                        "unique_report_name" : "Deletetest"
                    },
                ],
                "type" : 1
            },
            {
                "name" : "newdkdd",
                "values" : [
                    {
                        "report_name" : "aldkkd",
                        "report_heading" : "aldkkd",
                        "background" : "#f0f2f5",
                        "grid" : false,
                        "report_data" : {
                            "sslsls" : {
                                "datasource" : "alias",
                                "source" : "3",
                                "title" : "sslsls"
                            }
                        },
                        "unique_report_name" : "aldkkd"
                    }
                ],
                "type" : 1
            }
        ],
        "unique_report_id" : 986219
    }
```

Pymongo mongo query

```
mycol.update_one({
    "structure.name": folder_name
    },
    {
    "$pull": {
            "structure.$[structure].values": {
            "report_name": report_name,
        }
    }},
    array_filters= [
        {
            "structure.name": folder_name
        }
    ],
upsert=True)
```

I am using above query to delete it is deleting the entire report
How can i delete only one key from the report_data key

Please  take a look

Answer (score 0):

Think with filtered positional operator and arrayFilters, you need to specify the key with `report_data.ber2` to remove the respective field via `$unset`.

```
db.collection.update({
  "structure.name": "New folder"
},
{
  "$unset": {
    "structure.$[structure].values.$[value].report_data.ber2": ""
  }
},
{
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      "structure.name": "New folder",
      
    },
    {
      "value.report_name": "Delete test"
    }
  ]
})
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/wDa-zEygY-e)